# Implementing simple Java program in C++ (Abstract class)

Tags: java, c++, arrays, polymorphism, abstract-class

Java (Works)

Abstract class Personnell with subclasses of Manager and Worker. getAnnualIncome() is the abstract function.

```
Personnell employee[] = 
{
    new Manager("Thomas", "Nasa", 1337, 250000),
    new Worker("Simon", "Netto", 1336, 6.98, 36)
};
System.out.println("Name\t\tAnnual Income");
for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++)
{
System.out.printf(employee[i].getName() + "\t\t£%.2f%n", employee[i].getAnnualIncome());
}
```

C++ (Doesnt work)

```
Personnell employee[] = 
{
    Manager ("Tom", "Ableton", 1234, 400000),
    Worker ("Simon","QuickiMart", 666, 40, 3.50)
};

cout << "Name\t\tJob\t\tAnnual Income"<< endl<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << employee[i].getName() << "\t\t"<< employee[i].getDept()<<"\t\t"<< employee[0].getAnnualIncome() << endl;
}
```

Error: array of Abstract class "Personnell" is not allowed:
function "Personnell::getAnnualIncome" is a pure virtual function

Tried a few different things to do with pointers but I still need to get my head around them. 
Thanks, Tom

Edit (adding definitions and declarations) 
Personnell has

```
virtual double getAnnualIncome()=0;
```

Manager has

```
double getAnnualIncome(); //declaration
double Manager::getAnnualIncome() //definition
{

return this->salary_;
}
```

Worker has

```
double getAnnualIncome(); //declaration
double Worker::getAnnualIncome() //definition
{
return (this->hourlyRate_ * this->hoursPerWeek_)*52;
}
```

doing what ajb said, the output is:

Name            Job             Annual Income

Tom             Ableton         400000

Simon           QuickiMart              400000 // Should be 7280

Comment: could you add the definitions and implementations of your classes, too?

Comment: Did you override `Personnell::getAnnualIncome` in both `Manager` and `Worker`??

Comment: I haven't tried this, but ... try changing `Personnell employee[] =` to `Personnell *employee[] =`, put a `new` in front of the `Manager` and `Worker` in the array values for employee, and change `employee[i].getName()` to `employee[i]->getName()` [and similarly for other fields].  You can't have an array of `Personnell` objects since that is abstract and the compiler won't know how big to make each array element.  That's why you need pointers.  P.S. I'm not a C++ expert so I won't guarantee that I have the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks that has got it closer to working. However all of the annualIncomes with the value of the first item in the array. i.e all the annual incomes are 400000

Comment: In that case, can you add my name to that list?  :) :) :)

Comment: Ummm ... `employee[0].getAnnualIncome()`???  Looks like a typo.

Comment: P.S. `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` looks wrong since there are only two persons in the array.

Comment: Yeah that was the typo. How do I mark your answer as solved. Thanks A lot ajb! I've got some studying to do with pointers I think ^^

Comment: @TomS Since I answered it as a comment, you can't.  But now that I know it's the right answer (I wasn't sure), I'll put it in as an answer, then you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an array of `Personnell` objects, because `Personnell` is an abstract type, and the compiler won't know how big to make each array element.  So you need to use pointers.  (It works in Java because, in effect, Java automatically uses pointers.)

Change the `employee` definition to

```
Personnell *employee[] = 
{
    new Manager ("Tom", "Ableton", 1234, 400000),
    new Worker ("Simon","QuickiMart", 666, 40, 3.50)
};
```

and instead of

```
cout << employee[i].getName() << "\t\t"<< employee[i].getDept()<<"\t\t"<< employee[0].getAnnualIncome() << endl;
```

use `->` since `employee[i]` is now a pointer:

```
cout << employee[i]->getName() << "\t\t"<< employee[i]->getDept()<<"\t\t"<< employee[i]->getAnnualIncome() << endl;
```

(The last `employee[0]` is a typo and should be changed to `employee[i]`; also, `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` looks like a typo since there are only two elements in the array.)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, when you create an array with the type of the base class object, something called object slicing happens: i.e when you declare an array of an abstract class and you put child classes in it, only the abstract parts (i.e pure virtuals) are stored. And as you saw, you cannot call pure virtual functions because the objects in your `employee` array are sliced objects.